# How to install the Russian text in the functions of Picasa

Tags: localization, picasa

How to install the Russian text in the functions of Picasa. When I installed the program in Windows, there was a Russian version of the default.

Comment: If the answer below helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of its text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

Google officially [dropped support for Linux](http://googleblog.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/spring-cleaning-in-spring.html) of Picasa in April 2012.  **:-(**

So what you have is what you have, no further modifications will be made.

Извините...